How to get root-Access and/or update/extract firmware via UART
I would like to try to equip my non-specific China-Wall-Brick-WiFi-Router with root access and update it if necessary.
Here is a sample image of the device:

The problem is: The device has no official manufacturer, it is a noname China device. Accordingly, there is no manufacturer's website, nor are there any updates or downloads of the firmware.
Serial control via UART generates a shell output. Here it is theoretically possible to log on to the existing Linux system. The problem is that there is no access data. Trying standard access data such as root:root, root:admin, admin:admin or similar does not work.
The system has a modified version of OpenWRT (version OpenWrt Linux-3.10.14-p112871) and is booted with U-Boot 1.1.3 (Dec 25 2017 - 22:59:38).
I haven't had any experience with U-Boot yet, but it seems to be a slimmed down and limited version, as I only get very few commands displayed in the help in the U-Boot shell:
MT7628 # help
?       - alias for 'help'
bootm   - boot application image from memory
cp      - memory copy
erase   - erase SPI FLASH memory
go      - start application at address 'addr'
help    - print online help
loadb   - load binary file over serial line (kermit mode)
md      - memory display
mdio   - Ralink PHY register R/W command !!
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing)
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
printenv- print environment variables
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
rf      - read/write rf register
saveenv - save environment variables to persistent storage
setenv  - set environment variables
spi     - spi command
tftpboot- boot image via network using TFTP protocol
version - print monitor version

MT7628 # printenv
bootcmd=tftp
bootdelay=5
baudrate=57600
ethaddr="00:AA:BB:CC:DD:10"
ipaddr=10.10.10.123
serverip=10.10.10.3
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial
BootType=3

Environment size: 160/4092 bytes

How can I gain full root access to the device without damaging the current firmware?
I would prefer it if I could back up the complete firmware image in some way beforehand so that I can restore it in case of doubt. What is the best way to do this via U-Boot?
Are there perhaps bruteforce programs that connect via COM port (UART)? This would certainly also be a way of finding out the root password.

Not at all. Someone would have to implement such an access, and there's zero incentive to do so.
However, in theory your vendor needs you to give you the source code of the Linux kernel they're using, and since they're using OpenWRT, which is also GPLv2-licensed, also the whole build system for the image.
HOWEVER, this is GPLv2 – that means they do not give you the ability to actually flash a modified image to your system.

Like in the question already sayed: The problem is: The device has no official manufacturer, it is a noname China device. Accordingly, there is no manufacturer's website, nor are there any updates or downloads of the firmware.

@AdrianPreuss I know, that's why I said "in theory". Even if you had the personal address of the CEO of the manufacturer, that'd be still out of your legal reach, realistically. You simply won't get the kind of access you hope for.

by the way, it doesn't matter who the manufacturer is, legally. The party selling you the device is obliged to give you the source code; not the one originally producing the device. And you've sent money somewhere to get this device, so you know who the seller is. But again, not a realistic venue.

The seller is already unknown. The device was buyed over wish.com and the artikle/seller already no more listened like the most china pseudo companys
